# When I put self.customAnnotation in a loop it will not work. Can someone help. I am using the code from absolutions.com (asynchrony)

Tags: ios7, annotations, mkannotationview

Here is my viewForAnnotation:
When in loop, viewForAnnotation returns nil.
When i add the self.customAnnotation (alloc) line to the viewDidLoad statement or call it by itself, there is no problems and annotation = self.customAnnotation.  When in loop, annotation looses the self.customAnnotation.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id       <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
NSLog(@"viewForAnnotation");
    //if (annotation == self.mapView.userLocation) return nil;
    if (annotation == self.calloutAnnotation) {
        CalloutMapAnnotationView *calloutMapAnnotationView = (CalloutMapAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CalloutAnnotation"];
        if (!calloutMapAnnotationView) {
            calloutMapAnnotationView = [[AccessorizedCalloutMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CalloutAnnotation"];
            calloutMapAnnotationView.contentHeight = 78.0f;
            UIImage *asynchronyLogo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"asynchrony-logo-small.png"];
            UIImageView *asynchronyLogoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:asynchronyLogo];
            asynchronyLogoView.frame = CGRectMake(5,2,asynchronyLogoView.frame.size.width,asynchronyLogoView.frame.size.height);
            [calloutMapAnnotationView.contentView addSubview:asynchronyLogoView];
        }
        calloutMapAnnotationView.parentAnnotationView = self.selectedAnnotationView;
        calloutMapAnnotationView.mapView = self.mapView;
        return calloutMapAnnotationView;
    } else if (annotation == self.customAnnotation) {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[BasicMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomAnnotation"];

        annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Here is the actual loop assigned to a button for action:

```
- (IBAction)drawMap:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:0
                                                       error:&error];
    if (error != nil)
    {
        // handle the error as you want
    }
    //CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    //MKPointAnnotation *newAnnotation;
    NSMutableArray *newAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
    {
        self.customAnnotation = [[BasicMapAnnotation alloc] initWithLatitude:[dictionary[@"latitude"] doubleValue] andLongitude:[dictionary[@"longitude"] doubleValue]];
        [newAnnotations addObject:self.customAnnotation];
    }

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:newAnnotations];
    [self zoomToFitMapAnnotations:self.mapView];
}
```

Comment: Can you try to be clearer about what you're asking?

Comment: In viewForAnnotation, instead of `if (annotation == self.customAnnotation)`, you should use `if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[BasicMapAnnotation class]])` because `self.customAnnotation` only points to one annotation at a time and there's no guarantee that viewForAnnotation will get called one at a time after each add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anna's solution worked!

In viewForAnnotation, instead of if (annotation == self.customAnnotation), you should use if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[BasicMapAnnotation class]]) because self.customAnnotation only points to one annotation at a time and there's no guarantee that viewForAnnotation will get called one at a time after each add. –  Anna Jun 6 '14 at 2:22